# Magnitude of current

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

The current of a germanium diode at room temperature is 100 uA at a voltage of -1 V. Predict the magnitude of the current for voltages of 0.2 V and -0.2 V at room temperature. Repeat the prediction for operation at 20°C above room temperature?

I had tried $$i=I_se^{\frac{V}{nV_t}}$$ but I am getting +100 uA for -0.2 V and -300 mA for +0.2 V. However, the answer is -100 uA for -0.2 V and +300 mA for 0.2 V. Please help me with the signs.

Comment: How do you expect the diode to have the same current at -1V and -0.2v?  The question says the diode had 100uA current at -1 and you somehow calculated 100uA at -0.2v.

Comment: This seems like a not-a-particularly-well-phrased homework question. Room temp=? Threshold voltage = ?.

Comment: @GTElectronics That is just how the Shockley equation works.

Comment: For the temperature change you will need to understand how to apply the Boltzmann factor (large number probability/statistics) and you will also require the band gap information for germanium, too. What information do you possess leading into solving this question?

Answer (score 1):

The Shockley diode equation is:

$$I=I_S \left( e^\frac{V_\text{D}}{n V_\text{T}} - 1 \right)$$

\$I_S\$ and \$n\$ are parameters that need to be determined for each type of diode. \$n\$ is the ideality factor. For a perfect germanium crystal, I believe \$n=1\$ but it increases with crystal defects. Thus, technically, the question does not seem to have sufficient data points. However, since we are given the answer, perhaps we can determine what the instructor believes the ideality factor should be for a germanium diode based upon the supposed answers

Unfortunately, there is something wrong with the given data points.

A) 100 uA @ -1.0V

B) -100 uA @ -0.2V

C) 300 mA @ 0.2V

Data point A) should probably have a negative current, but that is easily fixed.
After fixing the sign of data point A, data points A) and B) have the same current, but since this is leakage current, it would not be surprising that they would be essentially equal.

Data points B) and C) are quite special. The magnitude of the voltages in each data point are the same (0.2V) and only their sign is different.

Data points such as these enable us to calculate \$I_S\$ and \$n\$ quite simply.

Call the current when the diode as forward biased with voltage \$V_0\$, \$I_+\$ and the current when the diode is reverse biased with voltage \$-V_0\$, \$I_-\$.

Then

\$I_S = -\frac{I_+ I_-}{I_+ + I_-} = - (I_+||I_-)\$

\$n = \frac{V_0}{V_T\cdot ln(-I_+/I_-)}\$

Plugging the values

\$I_+ = 300 mA\$

\$I_- = -100 \mu A\$

\$V_0 = 200 mV\$

into the above equations gives

\$I_S = -\frac{300000 \cdot -100}{300000 +  -100} \mu A = -\frac{-30000000}{299900} \mu A = 100.03 \mu A \approx 100 \mu A\$

\$n = \frac{200}{25 \cdot ln (-300000/-100)} = 0.999 \approx 1.0\$

The value of \$I_S\$ is not unreasonable for a leaky diode. The value of n for the germanium diode is essentially 1. Although we calculated it here, using two data points, I assume that the class was taught that germanium diodes have an n of 1 always. However, empirical studies give different values for n for different germanium diodes. For example see [this empirical study by Ben H. Tongue](http://kearman.com/bentongue/xtalset/16MeaDio/16MeaDio.html)

Knowing that

\$I_S = 100 \mu A\$

\$n = 1\$

\$V_T \approx 25 mA\$ at room temperature

\$ V_T \approx \frac{293+20}{293} \cdot 25 mA\$ for 20 degrees above room temperature

It is now a simple matter of plugging values into the Shockley equation to get the current under various conditions.

---

**The Math**

The Shockley equation can be re-arranged as

$$\frac{I}{I_S} + 1 = \left( e^\frac{V_\text{D}}{n V_\text{T}} \right)$$

So,

$$\frac{I_+}{I_S} + 1 =  \left( e^\frac{V_\text{0}}{n V_\text{T}} \right)$$

and

$$\frac{I_-}{I_S} + 1 =  \left( e^\frac{-V_\text{0}}{n V_\text{T}} \right)$$

So,

$$\frac{I_+}{I_S} + 1 = \frac{1}{\frac{I_-}{I_S} + 1}$$

$$(\frac{I_+}{I_S} + 1) (\frac{I_-}{I_S} + 1)=1$$

$$(I_+ + I_S)(I_- + I_S) = (I_S)^2$$

$$I_+I_- = -I_S(I_++I_-)$$

Therefore

$$I_S = -\frac{I_+I_-}{I_++I_-}$$

Also,

$$\frac{I_+}{I_S} + 1 =  \left( e^\frac{V_\text{0}}{n V_\text{T}} \right)$$

but

$$\frac{I_+}{I_S} + 1 = -\frac{I_+}{I_-}$$

So

$$-\frac{I_+}{I_-}=  \left( e^\frac{V_\text{0}}{n V_\text{T}} \right)$$

$$ ln (-I_+/I_-) = \frac{V_0}{n V_T}$$

Therefore

$$ n = \frac{V_0}{V_T \cdot ln (-I_+/I_-)} $$

---

**Empirical values for ideality factor (from Ben H. Tongue, link above)**

[image]
[image]